# Как передать в поток метод с несколькими параметрами ?

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, многопоточность

к примеру
Object.Method(a,b,c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если нужно запустить поток, передав несколько аргументов, то проще всего это сделать, создав новый класс.

```
{
    // data - класс, включающий все необходимые данные
    Data data = new Data(...);
    Thread thread = new Thread (new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoWork));

    thread.Start(data);
}

static void DoWork(object data)
{
    // TODO: ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

На текущий момент (2018 год), для запуска нового потока проще всего использовать лямбда-функции:

```
new Thread(() => Object.Method(a, b, c)).Start();
```

При этом вам не нужно создавать класс-обёртку для ваших данных: данные хранятся в замыкании лямбда-функции.

---

Ещё более хорошим вариантом является использование TPL и async/await. При этом вы сможете легко возвращать данные из потока:

```
Task<int> t = Task.Run(() => Object.GetSomething(a, b, c));
int result = await t;
```

Answer (score 2):

Например использовать параметризированный конструктор потока Thread. [Пример с МСДН](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h2f2459.aspx). Чтобы передать несколько значений оберните их в класс и передавайте в метод.