# Как передать метод с параметрами в Thread?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Как метод Fill запихнуть в новый поток?
Как заставить это работать?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    Thread myThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Fill));
                    myThread.Start(a);
                    myThread.Name = "Поток " + i.ToString();
                }

     static void Fill(int[] a)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
                    a[i] = rand.Next(-100, 100);
            }
```

Comment: `var therad = new Thread(arg => Fill(arg)); therad.Start(a);`

Comment: Заработало, а как с несколькими параметрами, например : Sort(a, 0, a.Length - 1)

Comment: `var thread = new Thread((dynamic arg) => Sort(arg.Array, arg.Start, arg.End)); thread.Start(new { Array = a, Start = 0, End = a.Length - 1 })`.

Comment: для ознакомления вам лучше почитать про `dynamic`, anonymous types, `System.Index`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если сигнатура вашего метода ничем не отличается от `ThreadStart`/`ParameterizedThreadStart`, то нужно просто передать делегат внутрь конструктора класса `Thread`:

```cs
var thread = new Thread(MyMethod);
```

---

Ситуация также проста, если нам нужно передать 1 аргумент, до типа, производного от `object`:

```cs
static void MyMethod(string @string) { ... }
```

В таком случае можно просто создать лямбду-обёртку<sup>1</sup>:

```cs
var thread = new Thread(arg => MyMethod(arg as string));
thread.Start("My String.");
```

---

А вот с передачей нескольких параметров не так всё просто. Например, у нас есть след. метод:

```cs
static MyOtherMethod(int a, string b, double c) { ... }
```

Можно просто пойти в лоб и следать что-то типо [такого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/807057/276432):

```cs
var thread = new Thread(() => MyOtherMethod(a, b, c));
thread.Start();
```

Это хороший метод, он полезен своей читаемостью, но при каждых новых значениях `a`, `b` или `c` создаётся новая лямбда, что не есть хорошо. Это можно использовать при редких/единичный созданиях нового потока, но не при переодических.

Поэтому можно создать новый тип, и передавать экземпляр этого типа:

```cs
// всегда `class`, т.к. быстрее оборачивается в `object`
class MyThreadArgs
{
    // Можно использовать вместо полей св-ва:
    // public int A { get; init; }
    // Использование св-в *обязательно*, если класс публичный.
    public int A;
    public string B;
    public double C;
}
```

```cs
var thread = new Thread(arg => {
   var args = arg as MyThreadArgs;

   MyOtherMethod(args.A, args.B, args.C);
});
thread.Start(new MyThreadArgs { A = 13, B = "Other string.", C = 3.14 });
```

Этот метод быстр и *обязателен* в случае, если тип передаваемых аргументов публичный, но гораздо изящнее выглядит метод с анонимными типами и `dynamic`:

```cs
var thread = new Thread((dynamic args) => MyOtherMethod(args.A, args.B, args.C));
thread.Start(new { A = 13, B = "Other string.", C = 3.14 });
```

Но у вас может возникнуть логичный вопрос: как мы лямбду, принимающую `dynamic` представили как `ParameterizedThreadStart`, принимающий `object`? Всё просто: `dynamic` — это тот же `object`, только компилятор даёт нам возможность пользоваться этим синтаксическим сахаром (вместо сложного `(int)args.GetType().GetProperty("A").GetValue(args)` делать простое `args.A`).

---

Но, как и любого красивого кода, есть обратная сторона: он медленный. Случай с `dynamic` не стал исключением, т.к. необходимые поля/св-ва/методы находятся не статически (во время компиляции), а динамически (во время исполнения программы).

---

<sup>1</sup> — в коде не используются nullable классы.

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё предупредить автора, что `dynamic` - это в общем случае медленно.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov прочитано, учтено, добавлено

Comment: «Это можно использовать при редких/единичный созданиях нового потока, но не при переодических.» — ну так создание нового потока в любом случае на несколько порядков более дорогая операция, чем создание одного делегата. Так что мне кажется, тут экономить нет смысла.

Comment: @VladD просто подводка к другому примеру решения.